# seek any true in a column from a list of data frames in R

Tags: r, list, boolean

I have a list of dataframes containing only boolean (TRUE / FALSE) columns.

I need to know if any of these columns contains any TRUE value (all are expected to be false and in fact, all are FALSE), but I'm getting just nonsense.

```
mylist <-
  list(df1=data.frame(
    "column11" = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
    "column12" = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
  ),df2=data.frame(
    "column21" = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
    "column22" = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
  ),df3=data.frame(
    "column31" = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
    "column32" = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
      ))

lapply(mylist, function(x) any(TRUE))


$df1
[1] TRUE

$df2
[1] TRUE

$df3
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason the anonymous function doesn't work as expected is because its argument is not being used, instead `any()` is checking if the value `TRUE` is `TRUE`.  It also needs to be passed a logical vector, not a data.frame.

If you want to check if any column in the data.frame has a `TRUE` value use:

```
sapply(mylist, function(x) any(unlist(x)))

  df1   df2   df3 
FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

If you want to check if any particular column has a `TRUE` value, use:

```
sapply(mylist, sapply, any)

           df1   df2   df3
column11 FALSE FALSE FALSE
column12 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: If the df's are big, `as.matrix` is an order of magnitude faster than `unlist` and the result is the same because `any` will treat the matrix as a vector. Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

An elusive `rapply` option:

```
rapply(mylist, f = any, how = 'unlist')

df1.column11 df1.column12 df2.column21 df2.column22 df3.column31 df3.column32 
       FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE 

do.call(rbind, rapply(mylist, f = any, how = 'list'))

    column11 column12
df1 FALSE    FALSE   
df2 FALSE    FALSE   
df3 FALSE    TRUE
```

And with coercion:

```
sapply(rapply(mylist, f = any, how = 'list'), any)

  df1   df2   df3 
FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We use `lapply()` for each `dataframe` in `mylist`then we use `apply` for each column of `dataframes`.

```
abc = function(x) {
  tf = apply(x, 2, FUN = any)
}

lapply(mylist, FUN =  abc )
```

Output:

```
$df1
column11 column12 
   FALSE    FALSE 

$df2
column21 column22 
   FALSE    FALSE 

$df3
column31 column32 
   FALSE     TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `?any`

> Given a set of logical vectors, is at least one of the values true?

A `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes, but a `data.frame` is not.  One option is to convert to `matrix` and use `any`

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) any(as.matrix(x)))
```